# Duplicate IO with file descriptors

Tags: bash, logging, io, file-descriptor, tee

I would like to route a file descriptor to **multiple** places at the same time.  For instance I would like every command in my script to print stdout to /dev/ps/9 and ./myscript.stdout  at the same time.

I'm looking to achieve similar results as piping every command in a script (or a section of a script) into `tee`, perhaps with file descriptors.  I also want the ability to restore default output behavior later in the script.

This code doesn't work, but it's an attempt at expressing my intent.  To restore stdout as FD 1 later, I copy it into FD 4.

```
exec 3>(tee /dev/ps/9 ./myscript.stdout)
exec 4>&1
exec 1>&3
```

Restore normal output behavior, deleting FDs 3 and 4.

```
exec 1>&4
exec 4>&-
exec 3>&-
```

Comment: For reference, what I'm trying to do is similar to this post.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5808362/bash-how-to-redirect-stdin-stderr-then-later-revert-fds

Comment: As I read it, your question has the same answer as [that similar post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5808362/bash-how-to-redirect-stdin-stderr-then-later-revert-fds).  If so, this is a duplicate.  If not, you should try to explain _clearly and precisely_ how this differs.

Comment: THAT post is effective in describing how to reroute file descriptors for a duration of code and revert to normal behaviour at some point.  Nowhere in that post (answers or otherwise) does anybody mention routing io to multiple places at the same time.. thanks @John1024 , upon my review, I noticed how poorly stated the question was.. hopefully my edits can clear it up for everyone

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I would like every command in my script to print stdout to /dev/ps/9
>   and ./myscript.stdout at the same time.

```
exec 1> >(tee ./myscript.stdout >/dev/ps/9)
```

The above combines redirection and process substitution.  With redirection alone, one can send stdout to a file.  For example:

```
exec 1> filename
```

However, with bash, filenames can often be replaced with commands.  This is called *process substitution* and it looks like `>(some command)` or `<(some command)` depending on whether one wants to write-to or read-from the process.  In our case, we want to write to a `tee` command.  Thus:

```
exec 1> >(some command)
```

Or, more specifically:

```
exec 1> >(tee ./myscript.stdout >/dev/ps/9)
```

Note that we have to maintain the space between the redirect (`1>`) and the process substitution (`>(tee ./myscript.stdout >/dev/ps/9)`.  Without the space, it would look like we were trying to append to a file whose name starts with a parens and this would generate a `bash` error.

For more information on this see the sections entitled "REDIRECTION" and "Process Substitution" in `man bash`.

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you.  The only reason I haven't accepted this answer yet is because I still don't understand exactly why this works.. I've opened up my own answer (as a community wiki) with your suggestion as part of an example script.. Hopefully somebody comes along and helps explain this.  Feel free to add to the community wiki if you like...

Comment: @Shane I updated the answer with some explanation of process substitution.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

random=$$ # generate a random seed number to name the log files with
out=out.$random
err=err.$random
dev=`echo $(who -m) | cut -d' ' -f2` # for finding the right pseudo-terminal
: >$out # create the log files or empty their contents
: >$err # ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

exec 1> >(tee ./$out >/dev/$dev) # I don't know how this works but it does
exec 2> >(tee ./$err >/dev/$dev) # ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
echo # writing directly to the pts in /dev doesn't look right until sending a blank line

##########################################

echo 'hello'

for i in `seq 0 1 10`; do
    echo $i
done

bad_command
```

#### THANKS @John1024

Here's a script for anybody else wishing to test this out.

Could somebody please explain in detail the exec lines to me.

For instance, why is there a blank space after the arrow in:

```
exec 1>
```

?

Comment: the space is so it will not be interpreted as a append redirection. The `>(...)` part is having a process act like a file that can be written to.

Comment: @programmerjake  .. If I write `command >/dev/null` the absence of a specified file descriptor is an implicit fd1.. I'm having trouble understanding why this is different from `exec 1>; exec >(...)` or `exec 1>(...)`

Comment: the `exec 1> >(command)` redirects fd 1 into the input of `command`. it could also be written `exec > >(command)`. it is like using a pipe from that fd to `command` for the rest of the script.

Comment: Why are you using `dev=\`echo $(who -m) | cut -d' ' -f2\``?  If you are looking for the i/o device name for the current terminal, you can just use `/dev/tty`.

Answer (score -1):

```
#!/bin/bash
logfile=$$.log
exec > $logfile 2>&1 | tee
echo "test"
```

The `$$` does a random seed number which is optional.

Comment: I just ran this and It is not working for me... Which version of bash are you using @PhysicalChemist ?

Comment: I am GNU bash, version 4.3.18(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin13.2.0). Are you executing it as a .sh file? This sends the output to the logfile and it prints it to the terminal.

Comment: Also, check to see if you have tee. You can try `exec > $logfile 2>&1 | tee $$.log` in the script, but it was not needed for me. Try turning off the random seed.

Comment: Ya, I definitely have tee.. I am running bash version 4.3.11 linux-gnu.... No idea.  surprised it works for you

Comment: Hmm linux vs unix perhaps. John1024 gave a nice solution, I hope that works out for you.

Comment: `| tee` does nothing, it is the same as `| cat`